# Fast Fourier Transform FFT for Lua?

Tags: audio, lua, signal-processing, fft

Does anyone have an implementation of the Fast Fourier Transform, that works with Lua ?

I want to use it on a sound sample, which I've loaded into Lua as an array of 16 bit signed ints. I wish to FFT the data and plot the freq spectrum.

I need an implementation that will work with Ansca Corona's version of Lua (loadstring not supported, which is used by complex.lua)

Answer (score 4):

You should have a look at [LuaFFT](http://www.mindfarming.de/luafft/). It's [MIT licensed](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php), so it should be fairly flexible to use.

**EDIT :** You could also take a look at [NumLua](http://numlua.luaforge.net/). [Here](https://github.com/carvalho/numlua) is its github site. It depends on BLAS/LAPACK, FFTW, and HDF5. You may be able to get this to work since it implements its own [complex number](https://github.com/carvalho/numlua/blob/master/complex.c) data-type.

Comment: I tried it, but it's dependant on complex.lua, which used loadstring and is consequently not support by my version of Lua (Ansca Corona)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry If I am a bit late.

But some time back I requested the author of complex.lua to eliminate loadstring - specifically for using it with Corona.

Here it is . 
https://github.com/davidm/lua-matrix/blob/master/lua/complex.lua

Answer (score 0):

You should use lua-torch based implementation, like https://github.com/soumith/torch-signal